# How do i embed a page in a extension?

Tags: javascript, html

I have currently been trying to create a Embed Iframe inside of a extension by using iframe it doesnt load and i tried using the page source as the popup.html and it wont work im trying to make a small window that displays a website and will load it and allow me to search via the extension without having to use the tab like using a embed stackoverflow or youtube if i use the page source everything looks fine until i put something int he search bar and press search i want to develope a extension that essentially acts like a embed frame

Comment: Can you please structure the question a bit more? The grammar errors and the lack of punctuation is not helping understanding what your goal is. Also, if possible try to provide a working (or non working) example from jsfiddle or codesandbox or similar tools to people could understand what you have already tried and what issues you are facing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.